# Modal Popup for Selecting an Option [jQuery]

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

In my application I want to present a list of choices for a user to pick from in a modal popup. I'll be using the value they select in the 'parent' page.

I've looked into nyroModal, but none of the examples include a return value after the modal closes. I'm assuming this is because its opening up the content with a new HTTP request, which isn't going to lend itself well to returning a value.

Any suggestions for libraries / ways to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), and display Inline content as a modal dialog.

That way, you can query the inline elements (that will be hidden when the dialog is closed) for the data entered.

Comment: Trying this out, looking promising so far. How do you close the modal after the user has performed an action without them having to manually click close also?

Comment: That's right.  Alternatively, you could specify the dialog not to be Modal, and it would close if you click behind it.

Answer (score 1):

why not just use the jquery-ui dialog?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

we use [JModal](http://code.google.com/p/jmodal/). It works well and does what you described.